# How can I decrypte the data in this SQLite Database file

Tags: encryption, decryption, unknown-data

I have this SQLite Database file

https://we.tl/t-RwKqYyS3D7

When I open it in notepad++, I got some decoded strings. I was trying to clean it and show only the strings without the symboles but then I found this website

https://filext.com/online-file-viewer.html

When I open that file there, it show a db table and the text column have only numbers.

I was thinking, maybe that's the strings but encrypted ?

Hope someone have an explanation for that numbers and maybe a way to decrypte it.

Example of the numbers

```
92,91,72,49,93,32,32,39,97,98,32,32,97,119,98,60,98,114,62,10,60,98,114,62,10,97,32,112,114,105,109,105,116,105,118,101,32,119,111,114,100,59,60,98,114,62,10,60,98,114,62,10,102,97,116,104,101,114,44,32,105,110,32,97,32,108,105,116,101,114,97,108,32,97,110,100,32,105,109,109,101,100,105,97,116,101,44,32,111,114,32,102,105,103,117,114,97,116,105,118,101,32,97,110,100,32,114,101,109,111,116,101,32,97,112,112,108,105,99,97,116,105,111,110,41,46,32,67,111,109,112,97,114,101,32,110,97,109,101,115,32,105,110,32,34,65,98,105,45,34,46,60,98,114,62,10,60,98,114,62,10,60,98,114,62,10,75,74,86,58,32,99,104,105,101,102,44,32,40,102,111,114,101,45,41,102,97,116,104,101,114,40,45,108,101,115,115,41,44,32,88,32,32,112,97,116,114,105,109,111,110,121,44,32,112,114,105,110,99,105,112,97,108,46,60,98,114,62,10
```

Or maybe a regex to clean all the file

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open that file using SQLiteStudio to get that information.

Steps:

1. [Download SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/) and install it
2. Drag the file (Strong.isa_lex) onto the left sidebar in SQLiteStudio and click OK
3. Double-click on the new database ("Strong")
4. You will see 2 tables, "Lemma" and "TBInfo", both with 2 columns each.
5. Right-click on table "Lemma" and Generate query for table > SELECT
6. Hit F9
7. Perform steps 5 and 6 for TBInfo as well

Now you have all the data.

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thank you so much Steve. Do you know a regex to remove \[H7] and many other like that ?

Comment: Not a problem! Unfortunately I'm not well versed with regex, so I won't be of much help there, sorry!

Comment: no problem, thank you my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

those numbers you pasted are ordinals for the respective characters

92 is ordinal for escaped backslash

```
ord('\\')
92
```

you can use a for i in blah construct with python to print them up

```
python
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input = [92,91,72,49,93,32,32,39,97,98,32,32,97,119,98,60,98,114,62,10,60,98,114,62,10,97,32,112,114,105,109,105,116,105,118,101,32,119,111,114,100,59,60,98,114,62,10,60,98,114,62,10,102,97,116,104,101,114,44,32,105,110,32,97,32,108,105,116,101,114,97,108,32,97,110,100,32,105,109,109,101,100,105,97,116,101,44,32,111,114,32,102,105,103,117,114,97,116,105,118,101,32,97,110,100,32,114,101,109,111,116,101,32,97,112,112,108,105,99,97,116,105,111,110,41,46,32,67,111,109,112,97,114,101,32,110,97,109,101,115,32,105,110,32,34,65,98,105,45,34,46,60,98,114,62,10,60,98,114,62,10,60,98,114,62,10,75,74,86,58,32,99,104,105,101,102,44,32,40,102,111,114,101,45,41,102,97,116,104,101,114,40,45,108,101,115,115,41,44,32,88,32,32,112,97,116,114,105,109,111,110,121,44,32,112,114,105,110,99,105,112,97,108,46,60,98,114,62,10]
>>> for i in input:
...     print(chr(i),end="")
...
\[H1]  'ab  awb<br>
<br>
a primitive word;<br>
<br>
father, in a literal and immediate, or figurative and remote application). Compare names in "Abi-".<br>
<br>
<br>
KJV: chief, (fore-)father(-less), X  patrimony, principal.<br>
>>>
```

or you can dump the database to a textfile by redirecting this with python

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(".\copysql")
cur = conn.cursor()

res = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Lexicon")
for a in res:
    print(a)

res = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TBinfo")
for a in res:
    print(a)
```

Comment: Man, you're awesome, thank you so much for your time and the explalantion.